# Is there anyway to highlight my variable names and numbers a different color in IDLE for python?

Tags: python-idle

Basically, I want my variables and numbers to be more visible while I am coding in IDLE.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps:

1. Go to OPTIONS -> CONFIGURE IDLE -> HIGHLIGHTS
2. You will now see some "example code" with highlighting and colored fonts. Here is a picture:
   [image: PICTURE]
3. Inside the Green box you will see code components like Keywords, identifiers etc. What you want is to click **any of the variables** shown **inside the green box** (shown in the picture)
4. After you have clicked (for example "var0") make sure "Foreground" is selected and look at the **Orange Box** and click "Choose Color For:"
5. Choose any suitable color which you can easily distinguish from the background color. Like If I am using a **dark background**, I would choose **Yellow color** to easily spot my variables.
6. Save your new theme with a **name**
7. Click "apply" and you are set!

### Here is and explaination of what we did

- When you were selecting "code elements" (keywords and the likes) in *point 3*, you were actualy selecting the elements you want to change the appearance of.
- "Foreground" represents the color of the **Font**, while "Background" represents the color with which the specified "code element" will be Highlighted.

**NOTE:** Now I did'nt say any about highlighting you variables, because IDLE will count **any text including whitespaces and variables** as "Normal code", and will highlight them all without regard. Means that all white spaces will be highlighted with the same color as well. We don't want that.

> You could use an alternative and more efficient IDEs for Python
> development. My personal recommendation will be Pycharm, as it takes care of many trivial stuff (including variable highlighting) and lets you code in peace. But of course there are other alternatives as well. Whatever floats your boat!

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, "Not currently."

Identifiers constitute the majority of program code outside of comments and strings.  It would make no sense to color then specially.  It would be difficult to separate 'your' identifiers ('variables') from other identifiers.  So I would reject this idea.

Number literals are a different story.  I just looked at a .py file in Windows Notepad++.  It highlights number literals (actually, any sequence of non-blanks beginning with a digits, which is too much).  This looks potentially useful and 0 and 1 are clearly different from O and l.  I believe this could be added to IDLE's colorizer, and will think about it.   But this is the first request I have seen.  So no promises.